# 'to take' and 'in cash'

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have the sentence

> I'm taking £50 in cash.

**Edit**: I found it in a dictionary from the article about 'cash'.

But there are so much meanings of the verb 'to take' that I can't find exact definition of this 'take'! Could you help me to find it, please?

Comment: We need more context to know what it means here.

Comment: I found it in a dictionary from the article about 'cash'. I think the context is like 'I have £50 in cash', but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, this may have a variety of meanings. Some likely ones which don't require elaborate backstories are:

- You are *choosing to receive* that part of what is owed you in cash.
  *I'm depositing my paycheck at the bank and taking £50 in cash.*
  *I'm taking £50 in cash, and the rest as a cheque.*
- You are *planning to carry* so much cash when you go somewhere.
  *I'm taking £50 in cash for drinks in the interval; we can do a late supper on my credit card*.
  *I'm taking £50 in cash to Bob, to buy his bicycle.*
- You are *removing* that sum from a repository.
  *I'm taking £50 in cash out of the register, but you'll have plenty left to make change.*
  *I'm taking £50 in cash I found in his sock drawer, but there's nothing here we can fence.*